# Can't open Excel spreadsheet after datagridview export from vb .net

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have the following code that takes a datagridview and exports its content to excel. This is all working fine. However, I would like to have the new spreadsheet launch after it is done. Currently I receive the following error when it gets to the line to open excel:

> Excel cannot open the file 'exported.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btlXLSExport.Click
    Dim fs As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\exported.xlsx", False)
    fs.WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
    fs.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>")
    fs.WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet xmlns:ss=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">")
    fs.WriteLine("    <ss:Styles>")
    fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Style ss:ID=""1"">")
    fs.WriteLine("           <ss:Font ss:Bold=""1""/>")
    fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Style>")
    fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Styles>")
    fs.WriteLine("    <Worksheet ss:Name=""Sheet1"">")
    fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Table>")
    For x As Integer = 0 To dgCustomers.Columns.Count - 1
        fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Column ss:Width=""{0}""/>",
                     dgCustomers.Columns.Item(x).Width)
    Next
    fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Row ss:StyleID=""1"">")
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgCustomers.Columns.Count - 1
        fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>")
        fs.WriteLine(String.Format(
                     "                   <ss:Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</ss:Data>",
                                  dgCustomers.Columns.Item(i).HeaderText))
        fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>")
    Next
    fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>")
    For intRow As Integer = 0 To dgCustomers.RowCount - 2
        fs.WriteLine(String.Format("            <ss:Row ss:Height =""{0}"">",
                                  dgCustomers.Rows(intRow).Height))
        For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgCustomers.Columns.Count - 1
            fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>")
            fs.WriteLine(String.Format(
                         "                   <ss:Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</ss:Data>",
                                       dgCustomers.Item(intCol, intRow).Value.ToString))
            fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>")
        Next
        fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>")
    Next
    fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Table>")
    fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Worksheet>")
    fs.WriteLine("</ss:Workbook>")
    fs.Close()

    Dim wapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim wsheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    Dim wbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    ' Dim wrange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

    ' Dim chartRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range



    wapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    wbook = wapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\exported.xlsx")
    wsheet = wbook.Worksheets(1)


End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try to rename `exported.xlsx` to `exported.xls`

Comment: I should have added that to the OP. I have tried both XLS and XLSX file extensions with the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Every day there is a question about "Excel not working", "Excel not opening"... I really don't understand, why doing it this way? Yesterday someone complained about Excel not opening `html` file built off `DataGridView`. Get the empty template file, use `Microsoft.Ace.OleDb` to fill it. Works every time.

Comment: I am not trying to get data from an ODBC connection? Maybe I misunderstood what you are telling me. I am filling the datagridview from a web service. Others would like to be able to take that information into excel and manipulate the data, so I am wanting to dump the datagridview to excel (which works fine) but then I want to open that same excel file after the export for the viewer to see. This is the part that is not working. Presumably because when the file is created I am passing it wrong XML information and therefore not giving it the proper headers/etc...